# Ajax.BeginForm() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Ajax.BeginForm() not working when Html.EditorFor() contains special charactor <
It does not invoke the controller action on submit the form

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostForm", "Home", new AjaxOptions()))
{
    string myFormValue = "";
    @Html.EditorFor(x => myFormValue)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PostForm(string myFormValue)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
```

When i debug it seems to work:

[image]

May you post your code?